# getting a token with httr R package: worked once but stopped working after

Tags: r, curl, httr

I have the following `curl` command working just fine:

`curl -d '{"client_id": "shiny", "client_secret": "(secret)", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://(url)/api/token`

(replaced secret key and url with (secret) and (url).

But when I try to convert this to use in R with `httr` package, it doesn't work. I tried:

```
config <- list(
  "client_id" = "shiny",
  "client_secret" = "(secret)",
  "grant_type" = "client_credentials"
)

token <- POST(url = "https://(url)/api/token", config = list(),
              body = config, add_headers(), encode = "json")
```

It worked once but when I tried running the same command again I got this error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

I think I need to add some additional parameters to my command but can't figure out which one.

Any ideas are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `config = list()`? That seems out of place. Perhaps add `verbose()` to get more information about what's being sent. Maybe test by pointing both commands to a site like `https://httpreq.com/` and compare the requests to see what's different between the two methods. It likely has more to do with the server and since we don't know anything about that, it's hard to say for sure what's happening. Perhaps contact whomever runs the server for more help.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick! I'll remove config = list(), you are right. It just worked again, so I need to understand what is actually causing the issue... Thanks!